# Were Data and Lore created as a 'pair'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-data, androids, star-trek-picard

We know of three [Soong-type androids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soong-type_android), [B4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B-4), [Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data) and [Lore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lore). It is possible there were others.

We know in [*Picard* 1x01 "Remembrance"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Remembrance_(episode)) - that the type of Synth that Dahj and Soji are, are created in pairs.

> Jurati says it would be possible to create a female android from Data's positronic neuron, using the plural "they."
>
> Picard asks, "twins?"
>
> Jurati concurs: they were created in pairs.
>
> "So there's another one..." Picard muses.

We have other information on Data from the episodes:

- [TNG 2x09 - "The Measure of a Man"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Measure_Of_A_Man_(episode))
- [TNG 7x01 - "Descent Part II"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Descent,_Part_II_(episode))

but only provide scattered information.

That leads to a few possibilities:

1. That Data/Lore and B4 are of a different type of Android to Dahj and Soji, and are not under the constraint to be created in pairs
2. Dr Soong created Data and Lore as a pair, and B4 had a pair was was never seen
3. Dr Soong created lots of Androids we didn't see, and Data and Lore are not a pair.

**Were Data and Lore created as a 'pair'?**

Comment: I am pretty sure that if they were, Picard would know. Also, I think that the creation in pairs refers to the new method of fractal cloning (or however it was called).

Comment: Dahj and Soji aren't even Data's first *daughters*. [Remember Lal!](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lal)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No. Soong created Lore first, then Data.

This is confirmed by Soong himself in TNG: Brothers:

> **DATA:** Lore also told me the colonists petitioned you to replace him with a less perfect android.
>   **SOONG:** The last thing you should think of yourself as, Data, is less perfect. The two of you are virtually identical, except for a bit of programming.
>   **DATA:** It was a lie. Another lie.
>   **LORE:** I would have proven myself worth to you, if you'd just given me a chance. But it was easier just to turn your back and build your precious Data.
>   **SOONG:** **You were the first.** You meant as much to me as Data ever did, but you were unstable. The colonists were not envious of you, they were afraid of you. You were unstable.
>   **DATA:** I am not less perfect than Lore.
>   **LORE:** Why didn't you just fix me? It was within your power to fix me.
>   **SOONG:** It wasn't as easy as that. The next, **the next logical step was to construct Data**. Afterward, I planned to get back to you, to fix you.
>   **LORE:** Next logical step.

[source](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/177.htm)

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 5):

Soong was attempting to create the [positronic brain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Positronic_brain), something which nobody in Star Trek canon has been able to replicate (meaning it is exceptionally difficult). Memory Alpha's [synopsis of B4 adds some clarity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B-4)

> B-4 was a prototype android constructed by Doctor Noonian Soong on Omicron Theta in the 2330s. He was one of three failed prototypes and the only one to survive a significant amount of time after his activation before the construction of Lore was successful.

Bruce Maddox is working from an entirely different methodology than Soong did. [Remembrance](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-picard-2020&episode=s01e01) made that clear (emphasis mine)

> JURATI: No one has ever been able to redevelop the science used to create Data.
>   Then came Bruce.
>   PICARD: Maddox.
>   JURATI: He recruited me out of Starfleet. Despite Data's death, we came so close.
>   Then we got shut down, and it crushed him.
>   PICARD: Where is he now?
>   JURATI: He disappeared after the ban.
>   PICARD: I've tried to find him, but You said "despite Data's death", meaning that any new synthetic would have to be made from Data.
>   JURATI: Advanced ones, yes. If you had Data's neural net, perfecting a flesh-and-blood host body would be relatively simple.
>   PICARD: But his neurons died with him.
>   JURATI: See, now you're coming around to that "no" I've been promising you.
>   PICARD: Does this mean anything to you? [shows her Dahj's double-ring necklace]
>   JURATI: Where did you get that?
>   PICARD: From my tea-drinking companion. The one you said couldn't exist.
>   JURATI: I really really wish you'd come here on my day off. **It's a symbol for fractal neuronic cloning.**
>   PICARD: I'm sorry?
>  
>   JURATI: It was a radical, beautiful idea of Maddox's.
>   His theory was that Data's entire code, even his memories, could be reconstituted from a single positronic neuron.
>   If there is a synth out there who is perfect, like you say Then Data, or some part of him --
>   PICARD: an essence of him --
>  
>   JURATI: Essence, yes. Would be alive. There'd be no way of knowing - without examining Dahj
>   [snip]
>   PICARD: Uh, I'm sorry? "Them"? 
>   JURATI: **They're created in pairs.**

The fact that Picard himself was surprised by there being a "pair", means this was new to him as well.

Answer (score 3):

No. Data was created after Lore with different programming.

From his [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_(Star_Trek)):

> In "Datalore", Data discovers his amoral brother, Lore, and learns that he was created after Lore.

Furthermore Data and Lore are not the only androids constructed by Dr. Soong:

> Because of Julianna Soong's inability to conceive children, Data has at least five robotic siblings (two of which are Lore and B-4). Later on, his "mother" is revealed also to be his positronic sister as the real Julianna Soong died and was replaced with an identical Soong-type android, the most advanced one that Dr. Soong was known to have built.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't exactly an authoritative source, could you get the quotes from the primary source to back this up?

Comment: Who are the other siblings?